# OrientDB http request failed...?

Tags: java, orientdb

I'm trying to do a "POST" method in Java. I create my output with the OrientDB method like this:

```
"http://xxxxxxxxxxx:2480/command/mydb/sql/CREATE VERTEX V SET name = ' datoAletarorio'"
```

I need to use the write and flush methods to send the command.

My DB is empty with this method.
Where is my error? Here is my code:

```
//...
PrintWriter out = null;
//...
conexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conexion.setDoOutput(true);
conexion.setRequestMethod("POST");

out = new PrintWriter(conexion.getOutputStream());

conexion.connect();
//...
String cumuloDatos1 = "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:2480/command/mydb/sql/CREATE VERTEX V SET name = ' datoAletarorio'"

out.write(cumuloDatos1);
out.flush();
//..
conexion.disconnect();
```

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/OrientDB-REST.html#command) says:

> The command-text can appear in either the URL or the content of the
>   POST transmission. Where the command-text is included in the URL, it
>   must be encoded as per normal URL encoding.

So you probably have to [encode the URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) before sending the request:

```
String cumuloDatos1 = 
     "http://xxxxxxxxxxx:2480/command/mydb/sql/" +
     "CREATE%20VERTEX%20V%20SET%20name%20%3D%20%27%20datoAletarorio%27"
```

Anyway, you should see messages in the logs for a 400 or similiar in the server, if the request isn't valid.